# Laravel 5.4 and elixir errors

Tags: css, node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-elixir

I want to simple adding new css tags into an imported scss file like:

```
@import "general/global"
```

with the content

```
body {
    background-color: #999;
}
```

It compiles with elixir (npm run dev and npm run watch; webpack) but I get errors in my console "unexpected token". I checkthes both compiled files app.css and app.js and i found this:
[image]

or
[image]

I tried to run "npm install" or "npm update" again, deleted node_modules folder etc. but nothing helps. Anyone an idea?

**EDIT:**
My wepback.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.browserSync('http://192.168.99.100/');

mix.js([
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',  
        'resources/assets/js/app.js'
    ], 'public/js/app.js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css');
```

using: bootstrap 4 alpha6 on windows 10 pro, laravel 5.4 latest

Comment: You should post your `webpack.mix.js` file.

Comment: I added the webpack.mix.js but I thing it's something with npm or windows.... still adding those unexcpected tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Docker / Virtualbox error. See this link:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=24905

For now a "sendfile off;" (using nginx) in my vhost.conf helped me.